# How to plot datetime corresponds to latitude and longitude on a map while drawing cyclone track?

Tags: python, matlab, cyclone

I am using ibtracks cyclone data. I want to draw a cyclone track and DateTime corresponding to lat and long points on the map using python. I am able to draw track but not getting how to plot DateTime. Here is my code and my file.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
import numpy as np
import tropycal.tracks as tracks
import datetime as dt

# load data
storm1 = cyclone.get_storm('IO012014')
lat = storm1['lat'][:]
lon = storm1['lon'][:]
date = storm1['date'][:]

# figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,9))
m = Basemap (projection='merc', llcrnrlon=50, llcrnrlat=5, urcrnrlon = 98, urcrnrlat=25, resolution='i')
m.etopo()
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90., 90., 10.), labels=[1,0,0,0], fontsize=10, linewidth=0.5, color='k')
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180., 180., 10.), labels=[0,0,0,1], fontsize=10, linewidth=0.5, color='k')
x, y = m(lon, lat)
m.plot(x, y, 'o-', color='r')
```

[my file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq6lD.png)

[my file looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nri7M.png)

Comment: How exactly do you want to plot the date/time?  As labels or something else?

Comment: I would like plot the date/time along the cyclone track (lat/lon data points)

Comment: Try using the [text](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) command.